# Unable to update an excel file in SP

Tags: 2010, 2013, excel, document

One of our users is currently trying to update an excel file that is saved directly to our SP document library. Whenever he tries to update it and save it the changes for some reason never save. It works when I do it and when another associate does it. He is currently using excel 2010. I am using 2013 and the other associate that got it to work is using 2010. Our SP site is 2013. Any information on why this may be happening would be much appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: Are you using a check-in/check-out system for the library? Something similar happened with one of my coworkers and it turned out he was saving it to his HDD and never bothering with the Check In button haha

Comment: It's not checked out on SP and the excel file itself isnt checked out to anyone.

Comment: Then after he checks it out, could you tell him to make some changes and then document that in the Check In dialog? This way you can see whether the issue is with the Excel 2010 incompatibility

Comment: Were not using the Check-in/check-out system currently. Should i try it to test this or no?

Comment: In that case, no, there is no need. You could try checking his MS Upload Center, sometimes Office is acting up and crashes when uploading documents. See if there are any files pending upload.

Comment: I'm thinking this might be part of the issue. I just checked his upload center, it doesnt show anything is pending but it doesn show anything has been uploaded in the history where in comparison to mine it shows that i have updated the excel file. Currently the office 365 site is down so using that resource for more information isnt possible right now but ill search around other sites. Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: In that case it looks like the issue is with MS Office. See if he has problems with other Office software, like Word or to try uploading Excel files to a different library. A re-install should fix the problem.

Comment: I just checked with my other associate he is using 2013 upload center as am I, the associate with the problem is using 2010 upload center and we are on a 2013 SP site. Is this the issue?

Comment: Oh, I thought only you had 2013, the other two had 2010, but it worked for one and not for the other. I think this might be the issue in this case.

Comment: yeah i have the full office 2013 and were using SP 2013. The associate that cant get this to work is using office 2010 and his upload center 2010. The associate that can get it to work is using office 2010 except for the fact that his upload center is 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file was being saved locally by default for some reason. After searching through the setting and tools of IE I found out that the user with the problem was running IE in compatability mode which was cause the file to be saved locally by default. Once the compatability mode was turned off everything was working as it should.